# Reduce the margin for one page so that a table fits over two pages

Tags: tables, fancyhdr

I have a problem. I am struggling with a table that goes over two pages. I have now solved this by putting the text in two columns, although it belongs in one.
Unfortunately, the table still looks terrible. Is there a way to reduce the header and footer a bit, or to reduce the lateral spacing a bit as well? It is important that the document should be printed later, so the lateral distance should only be reduced by a few cm. It would also be important to mention that the document has been rotated.

In summary, I would like to reduce the footer area and the header area so that the columns are larger and I have more space in the table.

[image]

Long MVP

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% load before geometry
\usepackage[a4paper, left={2.5cm}, right={2cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering text in X column %-----> commented
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{float} %----> added

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]


\chapter{CRIPS-DM}
\newpage
\begin{landscape}

{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\
    
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{6}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}}  \\ \hline 
    \endhead
    
    \hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    
    Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
    Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item Hintergrund
        \item Unternehmensziele
        \item Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace{0.3cm} Situation bewerten
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
        \item Erfordernisse
    \end{itemize}


& % -------------------
    Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Hintergrund
    \item Unternehmensziele
    \item Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Situation bewerten
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
    \item Erfordernisse
\end{itemize}
& % ---------------------
    Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Hintergrund
    \item Unternehmensziele
    \item Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Situation bewerten
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
    \item Erfordernisse
\end{itemize}
& % ----------------------
    Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Hintergrund
    \item Unternehmensziele
    \item Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Situation bewerten
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
    \item Erfordernisse
\end{itemize}
& % -----------------
    Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Hintergrund
    \item Unternehmensziele
    \item Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Situation bewerten
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
    \item Erfordernisse
\end{itemize}
& % ------------
    Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Hintergrund
    \item Unternehmensziele
    \item Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Situation bewerten
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
    \item Erfordernisse
\end{itemize}
% N E  W   R  O W
\\
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Annahmen und Beschränkungen
    \item Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
    \item Terminologie
    \item Kosten und Nutzen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Data-Mining-Ziele
    \item Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Projektplan erstellen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Projektplan
    \item Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
\end{itemize}
& %---------------
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Annahmen und Beschränkungen
    \item Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
    \item Terminologie
    \item Kosten und Nutzen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Data-Mining-Ziele
    \item Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Projektplan erstellen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Projektplan
    \item Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
\end{itemize}
&  %---------------
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Annahmen und Beschränkungen
    \item Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
    \item Terminologie
    \item Kosten und Nutzen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Data-Mining-Ziele
    \item Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Projektplan erstellen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Projektplan
    \item Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
\end{itemize}
&  %---------------
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Annahmen und Beschränkungen
    \item Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
    \item Terminologie
    \item Kosten und Nutzen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Data-Mining-Ziele
    \item Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Projektplan erstellen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Projektplan
    \item Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
\end{itemize}
&  %---------------

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Annahmen und Beschränkungen
    \item Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
    \item Terminologie
    \item Kosten und Nutzen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Data-Mining-Ziele
    \item Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Projektplan erstellen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Projektplan
    \item Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
\end{itemize}
&

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Annahmen und Beschränkungen
    \item Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
    \item Terminologie
    \item Kosten und Nutzen
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Data-Mining-Ziele
    \item Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3cm} Projektplan erstellen
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Projektplan
    \item Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
\end{itemize}
\\

\end{xltabular}
}
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}` instead of `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}` should help.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you very much! I didn't know it would be so easy.

Comment: One confusing aspect of rotating and pdflscape is that \textwidth stays unchanged, \textheight=\textwidth and \linewidth is the new horizontal distance (the original \textheight).  This is not true when using [landcape] for the whole document.